# Context free grammer for $L = \{a^i b^j a^n b^m \mid i + j = n + m\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Find a CFG for the following language:

$$L = \{a^i b^j a^n b^m \mid i + j = n + m\}$$

I'm not sure how I can do that context free. I know that I have to borrow one char from the left group for each char from the right group. but not sure how.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: With an automaton, it's easy. You use the stack to count (in unary) and accept when it's empty. And you remind yourself which part you're reading with states.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use non-terminals $X_{\alpha\beta}$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \{a,b\}$, that support the production $X_{\alpha\beta} \to \alpha X_{\alpha\beta} \beta$. You have to combine them somehow so that you obtain the language $L$, but I'll leave the details to you.